# How to effectively use knn in Stata

Tags: error-handling, machine-learning, stata, knn

I have two questions with executing discrim knn in Stata.

1) How do you properly code the command? I've tried various versions, but seem to always get an error that there are too many variables specified.

- The vector with the correct result is buy.
- I am trying: `discrim knn buy, group(train test) k(1)`

2) My understanding with KNN was that factor variables (binary) were fine for using KNN, even encouraged. However I get the error message that factor variables and time-series operators not allowed.

Lastly, though I know this isn't the best space for this question, should each vector be normalized for knn? I've heard conflicting responses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the error you're getting is

```
group():  too many variables specified
```

This is because you can only group by 1 variable with `knn`. `knn` performs discriminant analysis based on a single grouping variable, in your case, distinguishing the training from the test. I imagine your `train` and `test` variables are binary, in which case using only one of the variables is enough, as  they are merely logical opposites of each other. A single variable has enough information to distinguish the two groups.